# Does the word "Edition" go with the word "Summit"?

Tags: word-choice

is it correct to say "the Health Summit in its 9th **Edition**"?

Comment: is "Health Summit" something that has editions?

Comment: @Matt: well, that's the question here. (^_^)

Comment: Then I meant to ask: what is "Health Summit"? n_n;

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Why do you think Edition is appropriate (or not) for a summit?

Comment: I guess I understand why this question was closed, but I think the problem could be easily addressed if the poster would clarify what "Health Summit" is.

Answer (score 2):

If "Health Summit" is the title of a book that is periodically updated, then the ninth version published could be called the "9th edition".

If "Health Summit" is a meeting and you are thinking of the ninth time that this meeting was held, then no, you wouldn't call it the "9th edition". You'd call it the "9th Annual Health Summit" or the "9th Monthly Health Summit" or whatever the frequency is. Or if it's not held on any regular schedule, you'd probably just call it the "9th Health Summit".

If it's neither a book nor a meeting, please clarify what it is. But in any case, if it's not some sort of publication -- a book, a magazine, etc -- you wouldn't call it an "edition", except as a metaphor or a joke. (Hey, if I ever organize a publisher's convention, I think I'll refer to the annual meetings as "editions"! Or like Benjamin Franklin's famous epitaph: "The Body of B. Franklin, Printer; like the Cover of an old Book, Its Contents torn out, And stript of its Lettering and Gilding, Lies here, Food for Worms. But the Work shall not be wholly lost; For it will, as he believ'd, appear once more, In a new & more perfect Edition, Corrected and amended By the Author.")

Answer (score 0):

Edition is the "entire number of copies of a publication issued at one time or from a single set of type." It is always related to books or newspaper. Where as summit means "A conference or meeting of high-level leaders, usually called to shape a program of action."

These two words can never be used together. Summit cannot have number of copies because its a type of meeting.

Comment: ... unless there is a publication named "Health Summit". "Summit" also means "peak" of course.